# Doubt on Roots of a polynomial with rational coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, roots

I understand how $$1=0.999...= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac {9}{10^i}$$
$\quad \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$ (henceforth represented as $0.\overline 9$)

then does that mean that $x^2+x+1=0$ has the same roots as $0.\overline 9x^2+0.\overline 9x+0.\overline 9=0$

Comment: If by "roots" you mean "algebraic numbers", I think it must be true as the irreducible polynoms in $\mathbb{R}_{[X]}$ are at most of degree 2.

Comment: What does the sentence "If so, then does a given n-tuple of roots satisfy $2^{(n+1)}$ nth degree rational coefficient polynomials equated to zero?" mean?

Comment: It has the same roots as $2x^2+2x+2=0$ or, in general, $cx^2+cx+c=0$ for any $c\ne 0$. It has nothing to do with $1=0.999\dots$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does that mean that $x^2+x+1=0$ has the same roots as $0.\overline 9x^2+0.\overline 9x+0.\overline 9=0$

Yes, because that's two ways of representing exactly the same polynomial.

> If so, then does a given n-tuple of roots satisfy $2^{(n+1)}$ nth degree rational coefficient polynomials equated to zero?

This conclusion doesn't follow from the above, because the above just uses two ways of writing down the same polynomial.

I would actually argue that if an $n$-tuple is a root of an $n$th degree polynomial, then it is a root of infinitely many of them.  Because if $p(x) = 0$ for some $x \in \Bbb R^n$, then $\alpha p(x) = 0$ as well, for that same $x$ and for all $\alpha \in \Bbb R$.  Or take $\alpha \in \Bbb Q$ if you want to keep rational coefficients.  Still infinitely many of them, and either way, the polynomial $\alpha p$ is different from $p$ as long as $\alpha \ne 1$.

Answer (score 1):

> then does that mean that $x^2+x+1$ has the same roots as $0.\overline 9x^2+0.\overline 9x+0.\overline 9=0$

Yes, because the polynomial $x^2+x+1=0$ is the same polynomial as $0.\overline 9x^2+0.\overline 9x+0.\overline 9$.

---

There is **no** difference between the number $0.\overline 9$ and the number $1$. They are **the same number**. Every property that one satisfies, the other does as well. The difference between $1$ and $0.\overline9$ is the same as the difference between "Earth" and "the planet we live on".

---

> If so, then does a given n-tuple of roots satisfy $2^{(n+1)}$ nth degree rational coefficient polynomials equated to zero?

I don't know what that sentence means, please rephrase it.

Comment: It's asking if, given an $n$-tuple that solves one polynomial equation of degree $n$, can we conclude that the $n$-tuple solves $2^{n+1}$ such equations.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite sum tends towards $1$ as $i$ tends towards $\infty$. Therefore the sum to infinity $(0.999...)$ is equal to $1.$

So both equations are actually the same.

Comment: The sum is not just **equivalent** to $1$, it is **equal** to $1$.

Comment: I'm sorry about that blunder. My bad

Comment: Sorry again to ask a question in my answer, but the only difference I know are in the symbols and that one of them basically means always equal(like see below)could you direct me to the difference.

Comment: There is no such thing as "always equal". One number is either equal to another, or it is not.

Comment: $x^2 - 1$ is equivalent to $(x+1)(x-1)$ for all values of $x$. Whereas if $x^2 - 1$ is equal to 0, then $x^2 = 1$ and thus $x = 1$ for that particular case condition of the expression being equal to 0

Comment: Again, $x^2-1$ is not just **equivalent** to $(x+1)(x-1)$, it is **equal** to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64568/discussion-between-j-doe-and-5xum).